# Play AAC in SoundManager2 won't start

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, aac, soundmanager2

I converted audio file MP4 to AAC and then want to play that file in SoundManager2. If I use some software for Windows for convert, everying is fine, audio is playing well. But, on server side when MP4 file is converted to AAC using ffmpeg, file is loaded in SM2, but playing is not started.

I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.aac
```

Here is SoundManager2 log:

```
-- SoundManager 2: HTML5 support tests (/^(probably|maybe)$/i): mp3: true (preferring flash), mp4: true (preferring flash), ogg: true, wav: true -- soundmanager2.js:1156
-- SoundManager 2 V2.97a.20120916 (AS3/Flash 9) + HTML5 audio, high performance mode, custom (1ms) polling, wmode: transparent, flash debug mode, flashBlock mode -- soundmanager2.js:1156
soundManager::createMovie(): Trying to load /soundmanager/swf/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf soundmanager2.js:1156
soundManager::initMovie(): Waiting for ExternalInterface call from Flash... soundmanager2.js:1158
soundManager::externalInterfaceOK() (~0 ms) soundmanager2.js:1158
soundManager::init() soundmanager2.js:1158
soundManager: Attempting JS to Flash call... soundmanager2.js:1158
(Flash): SM2 SWF V2.97a.20120916 (AS3/Flash 9) soundmanager2.js:1158
Flash security sandbox type: remote soundmanager2.js:1158
(Flash): JS to/from Flash OK soundmanager2.js:1158
(Flash): Enabling polling, 1 ms interval soundmanager2.js:1158
-- SoundManager 2 loaded (OK) -- soundmanager2.js:1156
soundManager: Firing 1 onready() item soundmanager2.js:1158
threeSixtyPlayer.init() soundmanager2.js:1158
threeSixtyPlayer.init(): Found 1 relevant items. soundmanager2.js:1158
handleClick() soundmanager2.js:1158
soundManager.createSound(): ui360Sound0 (http://[private url]/out.aac?v=1350309261) soundmanager2.js:1156
soundManager.createSound(): Enabling usePolicyFile for data access soundmanager2.js:1158
SMSound() merged options: {
 id: ui360Sound0, 
 url: http://[private url]/out.aac?v=1350309261, 
 onplay: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onstop: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onpause: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onresume: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onfinish: { var nextLink; pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data... }, 
 onbufferchange: { if (this.isBuffering) { pl.addClass(this._360data.oUIBox,pl.css... }, 
 whileloading: { if (this.paused) { self.updatePlaying.apply(this); } }... }, 
 whileplaying: { self.updatePlaying.apply(this); this._360data.fps++; }... }, 
 useWaveformData: false, 
 useEQData: false, 
 usePeakData: true, 
 autoLoad: false, 
 autoPlay: false, 
 loops: 1, 
 multiShot: true, 
 multiShotEvents: false, 
 pan: 0, 
 stream: true, 
 usePolicyFile: true, 
 volume: 50, 
 useMovieStar: false, 
 isMovieStar: false, 
 bufferTime: 3
} soundmanager2.js:1158
(Flash): SoundManager2_SMSound_AS3: Got duration: 0, autoPlay: false soundmanager2.js:1158
SMSound.play(): Attempting to load "ui360Sound0" soundmanager2.js:1156
SMSound.load(): http://[private url]/out.aac?v=1350309261 soundmanager2.js:1156
SMSound.play(): "ui360Sound0" is starting to play soundmanager2.js:1158
fanOut: ui360Sound0: http://[private url]/out.aac?v=1350309261 soundmanager2.js:1158
(Flash): start (ui360Sound0): 0 soundmanager2.js:1158
SMSound._onbufferchange(): 1 soundmanager2.js:1158
SMSound._onbufferchange(): 0 soundmanager2.js:1158
SMSound._onload(): "ui360Sound0" loaded.
```

What can be a problem?

Comment: What version of ffmpeg are you using?  ffmpeg -version   And what is the operating system you are running it on?

Comment: ffmpeg 0.8.1-4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1

Comment: Have you tried using VLC to open/play the .mp4 and .aac files?  It could be your SoundManager2 is the problem.  Is the .AAC file the identical size when you create it on Windows vs Ubuntu?

Comment: Yup, plays well, but AAC is supported by SoundManager2. Also, SM2 plays files encoded with that software for Windows (Freemake Audio Converter)

Comment: Cannot help unless we have full ffmpeg output log

Answer (score 1):

SoundManager only (fully) supports MPEG-4 AAC audio. The file you are trying to play *could* be the "Non-Backwards Compatible" version of AAC defined in [**MPEG-2** Part 7](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=25040):

> [Part 7 (ISO/IEC 13818-7)](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec13818-7%7Bed4.0%7Den.pdf) of the MPEG-2 standard specifies a rather different, non-backwards-compatible audio format (also known as MPEG-2 NBC). Part 7 is referred to as MPEG-2 AAC.

As far as I know, only Safari (QuickTime) will play these files. Neither Chrome or Flash will play these files. However, the MIME type for the MPEG-2 AAC files is the same for the MPEG-4 varient so it's nearly impossible to know that the file is un-playable until after you attempt playback. (When asked, MPEG-LA responded "Because f*** you, that's why.")